# How should I simulate the electric potential field from a wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations

I was interested in making what I thought would be a simple simulation of an electron  encountering a positron by numerically solving the Schrodinger equation over several time steps, but I've run into 1 problem: the potential used in most textbooks (to solve the hydrogen atom for example) are still of a classical point particle, rather than a wavefunction. How do I generate the potential field from two real, moving and interacting wavefunctions?

Comment: You don't. First, in QT, there is always only one wave function, describing the whole system. Second, electric potential enters QT only as approximate description of action of classical external sources on the system. It is not easily possible to find electric potential due to part of a quantum system, like due to one electron in hydrogen atom or positronium. The hydrogen atom Hamiltonian has Coulomb interaction energy term, not external potential term. This Coulomb interaction terms is that of two points particles, not two wavefunctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electron and positron system can be denoted by the full wavefunction $\psi(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2,t)$ and its evolution is determined by the Hamiltonian (can be found from the classical energy):

$$\mathcal{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_1^2 -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_2^2 - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|} \tag{1}$$

So, for two particles interacting in 1D, you only need to solve the following differential equation for wavefunction $\psi(x_1,x_2,t)$:

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x_1,x_2,t) = (-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{|x_1-x_2|})\psi(x_1,x_2,t) \tag{2}$$

Then you can use your favourite numerical scheme to solve this "2D" partial differential equation.

You should notice that your need quadratic number of grid points $N^2$ for this two particles numerical solution. For the full wavefunction $\psi(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2,t)$, you need $N^6$ grid points which is not practical at all. It simply means that the position based method to find the wavefunction is not a good appoarch.

**Edit**: Regarding your question of point particle/wavefunction, you can interpret the equation (2) in the following way: The particles are still "interacting classically" with the electric attraction. If one of the particle is like a point charge confined very locally, then this point charge is actually interacting with another wavefunction over the whole space with probability amplitude $\psi(x_1,x_2,t)$.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at hwlau answer, you see that you can change coordinates from x1,x2 to the center of mass and relative coordinate. Just like you do for the Hydrogen atom.
If you work in the system of coordinates where the COM is stationary, the solution will be simple - identical to the Hydrogen atom, in fact.

My guess is, however, that this equation will not contain all the interesting physics, because there is no way for the two particles to annihilate and emit photons. To see that you will need to work in 2nd quantization, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to answer since the question interests me... and I dig up the topic in order to discuss.

@Unsym, what is the meaning of your wave function ? Your answer for me has a lack of sense or a proper formalism (is it Fock states based?).

So to answer the question, I think we should use Hartree conception of the potential field. Because each electrons or positrons are wave functions, the electrostatic potential remaining from them are not those from a point charge (or Dirac delta) but you are using it still... that makes no sens (it is a good approximation for hydrogen atom since we are using the Coulomb potential to describe proton field on the electron). The Coulomb's potential from the proton is justified by the fact that the radius of the proton is far smaller than a typical electron radius (say Bohr radius). But for a positron/electron system we have to use Poisson's equation (from Hartree), because the wave function should be the same order of length.

So I would propose simply (which is extremely logical from a physical point of view...):

$$ \Delta_1 V_1 (r_1) = - q \epsilon_0 \vert \Psi_1 (r_1) \vert^2 $$

$$ \Delta_2 V (r_2) = - q \epsilon_0 \vert \Psi_2 (r_2) \vert^2 $$

$V_1$ is the electrostatic potential created by $\Psi_1$ (say electron) and $V_2$ by $\Psi_2$ (say positron). Then the couple equations should be:

$$ \left( - \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_e} \Delta_1 - q^2 V_2(r_1 - r_2) \right) \Psi_1(r_1,r_2) = E_1 \Psi_1(r_1,r_2) $$
$$ \left( - \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_e} \Delta_2 - q^2 V_1(r_2 - r_1) \right) \Psi_2(r_2,r_1) = E_2 \Psi_2(r_2,r_1) $$

then because each wave function should depends on $r_1 - r_2$ we should have (transation invariance of Laplacian):

$$ \left( - \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_e} \Delta_{r_{1,2}} - q^2 V_2(r_1 - r_2) \right) \Psi_1(r_1,r_2) = E_1 \Psi_1(r_1,r_2) $$
$$ \left( - \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_e} \Delta_{r_{1,2}} - q^2 V_1(r_2 - r_1) \right) \Psi_2(r_2,r_1) = E_2 \Psi_2(r_2,r_1) $$

Then that gives 2 couples of self consistent field equations. We should probably fix a boundary condition on potentials at infinity or $r_{1,2} = 0$. What I want to say is that situation should be very different than an Hydrogen atom (proton is far smaller than electron/positron, plus the proton is considered fixed in Born approximation).